# JSTL while loop (without scriptlets)

Tags: jsp, jstl

Is there a way to create a while loop like structure with JSP, without using a scriptlet?

I ask as I have a linked list-like structure (specifically, printing the cause chain for exceptions) which AFAIK does not have an iterator interface to use forEach on.

Comment: Make the controller transform this structure into an Iterable one, and use forEach in the JSP. That's the role of the controller: prepare the data for the view.

Comment: @JBNizet Then that's an answer. Give it and I'll accept if I get no others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it by iterating over a list

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${requestScope['myErrorList']}">
${entry.message}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

EDIT:

You could have a method like the following to transform an exception and its causes into  list that later could be shown using a *forEach*

```
public static List<Throwable> getExceptionList(Exception ex) {
  List<Throwable> causeList = new ArrayList<Throwable>();
  causeList.add(ex);
  Throwable cause = null;
  while ((cause = ex.getCause()) != null && !causeList.contains(cause)) {
    causeList.add(cause);
  }
  return causeList;
}
```

For example:

```
try {
  ...
} catch (... ex) {
  request.setAttribute("myErrorList", getExceptionList(ex));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this solves the issue when the object in question does not implement a Collection interface.
Could you please elaborate?

Comment: this is a 'restriction' is you want to use _forEach_. But you could simply wrap your own list into any kind of collection inside your servlet.  You should do it before sending the response to the page. Plese give more detail on what king of object you want to iterate to

Comment: in the question: "cause chain for exceptions". throwable.getCause() gets the previous cause. I need to be able to iterate through all causes.

Answer (score 4):

What I ended up doing was a static loop with an arbitrary upper bound:

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="${<upper_bound>}" varStatus="loop">
    <c:if test="${!<exit_condition>}">
        <!-- loop output here -->
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${loop.last && !<exit_condition>}">
        <!-- overflow output here -->
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

This is really only useful only if you have some prior knowledge of the number of iterations, don't mind not displaying all information, or don't mind a potentially significant performance hit.

Keep in mind there is no early exit condition, so putting 2,147,483,647 as an upper bound would be a decidedly bad idea.

And for the curious, solution for outputting exceptions (sans formatting):

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="10" varStatus="loop">
    <c:if test="${!loop.first}">
        Caused By:
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${throwable != null}">
        Message: ${throwable.message} <br/>
        <c:forEach items="${throwable.stackTrace}" var="trace">
            ${trace} <br/>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${loop.last && throwable != null}">
        More causes not listed...
    </c:if>
    <c:set var="throwable" value="${throwable.cause}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 3):

The controller, whose role is to prepare the data for the view, should transform this non-iterable data structure into a collection that can be used by the `<c:forEach>` JSTL tag.

Comment: In the question: "does not have an iterator interface to use forEach on".

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that. Make the controller transform the structure into an Iterable one.

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to iterate over Collections, you can use `<c:forEach>` as a conventional loop equivalent by the following approach:

```
<c:set var="startIndex" scope="page" value="0"/>
<c:set var="endIndex" scope="page" value="12"/>

<select name="milestone_count" id="milestone_count">
    <option value="">-select-</option>
    <c:forEach begin="${startIndex}" end="${endIndex}" step="1" var="index">
        <option value="${index}">${index}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

This will produce a select drop down ranging from 0 to 12

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${myList}">
   ${item}"
</c:forEach>

<c:forEach var="entry" items="${myMap}">
  Key: <c:out value="${entry.key}"/>
  Value: <c:out value="${entry.value}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: In the question: "does not have an iterator interface to use forEach on"

Comment: Isee, then make one, like @JB Nizet said :)