# How to loop over a specific condition in JSTL? (e.g. while)

Tags: loops, while-loop, jstl, conditional-statements

I need to basically do a while loop in jstl, however the answers I've found so far are telling me to use forEach. However, I can't figure out why that is a solution.

I'm trying to run a piece of code only when a certain condition is true, not iterate through a list. Therefore, I won't be using the "items" attribute in the forEach tag.

So, how can one loop until a condition is false in JSTL?

Right now, I have something like this:

```
<c:forEach >
    <c:if test="${abcd:processNextRow (bean) eq 'true'}">
    <!-- This is the condition that should exit the 'while' loop. -->
        ${bean.arrayVar[0]}
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Just a feeling, it seems that you mix a logic in jsp, which shall be just a presentation layer. The logic belongs to a servlet.

Comment: Ad your question. There is no standard tag like while. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702459/jstl-while-loop-without-scriptlets

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<c:set>` to set the end condition of your loop

For exemple :

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="100" var="count">
   <c:if test="${abcd:processNextRow (bean) eq 'true'}">
      ${bean.arrayVar[0]}
      <c:set var="count" value="100"/>
   </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```